# run maven project with jenkins in Ubuntu.

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

Same configuration is working with window 10. but when i tried same configuration run with ubuntu, its showing an error.

[error message while running with jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpkVi.png)

Comment: You sure your code will work in Ubuntu?based on error seems like it is issue with code than plugin

Comment: Please try to run jenkins with Admin privileged

Comment: I've seen this sort of error whenever there's a process that's holding a lock on a file in some subfolder that Maven is trying to clean. Check that your Tomcat instance is really stopped (look for java processes in Task Manager that shouldn't be there). I've also created this issue for myself by opening the access log in a text editor, and then forgetting to close the editor after shutting down the Tomcat and trying to run a new build.

Comment: thanks for reply. I stopped tomcat and i gave all permission (read, write, execute) permission for that file. But still i am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

The clean plugin cannot delete the named folder. Make sure the Jenkins has the right to delete the folder and that it is not locked in some other way.

By the way: Copy the text of your error into the question, don't make a bad photo.

Comment: sorry for that bad photo.

Answer (score 0):

Some process has hold of the file `/home/xelpmoc-06/Documents/Doc/zerodha/target/classes/LoginZerodha/Zerodha/App.class`. 
`Java` process or `Eclipse` or some other program is doing some job with it. So that's why its showing that error. So please kill `Java` Process or restart `Eclipse`. May be your jenkins build failure, also can cause this to happen. So if nothing works out please restart your jenkins itself.

Here I am attaching a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489720/maven-failed-to-clean-project-failed-to-delete-org-ow2-util-asm-asm-tree?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that may be helpful to you. Please go through this. Hope this helps.