# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean on project ...: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete project\target

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I Am Getting BUILD FAILURE On Performing maven clean
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project datadriven: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete F:\workspace\project\target -> 
When I Saw Inside My Target Folder :

```
..\target\classes\META-INF\maven\com.project\datadriven\pom.xml

..\target\classes\META-INF\maven\com.project\datadriven\pom.properties

..\target\classes\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

..\target\test-classes\log4j.properties
```

These Files Were Present. But, I Haven't Kept These Files At This Place. Except MANIFEST.MF They Are Present In Another Place.

I Am New To Maven. I Can't Understand How To Solve This Problem.

```
<build> 
          <plugins> 
          <plugin> 
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
          <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
          <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>          
          <skipTests>false</skipTests>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
          <forkMode>once</forkMode>             
         <properties>
          <property>
          <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
          <value>false</value>
          </property>
          <property>
           <name>listener</name>
        <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter,com.abd.listeners.CustomListener</value>
           </property>
           </properties>          
           <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory> 
           </configuration>
          </plugin> 
          <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
          </plugin>             
          <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.5.1</version>
           <configuration>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
           </configuration>
           </plugin>            
           <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
           </plugin>
          </plugins>

          <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
            <include>log4j.properties</include>
            </includes>
           </testResource>
          </testResources>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.25</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
          <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
          <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>     
        </project>


    Below Are The Errors On Console I Got On Doing cmd:\\  mvn clean -X

     [INFO]Deleting F:\..project\target
     [INFO]Deleting directory F:\..project\target
          BUILD FAILURE
    [ERROR]Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project datadriven: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete F:\..project\target 
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project datadriven: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete F:\..project\target
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete F:\..project\target
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete F:\..project\target
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:249)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: Maybe your server didn't stopped yet

Comment: @Spara could be right, happens sometimes, but also eclipse gets lock on some files and maven cannot delete them. Try to exit eclipse and run maven from command line. Then start eclipse again.

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489720/maven-failed-to-clean-project-failed-to-delete-org-ow2-util-asm-asm-tree

Comment: this could happen some time (mostly when another process open the location) try deleting F:\..project\target manually and build project again

Comment: Thank You Everyone. Might Be The File Were Being Used By Some Other System. Now, It Am Able To Do Maven Clean Successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue. In my case I kept open the command prompt with the path pointing to my target folder of project. When I closed the command prompt and retied it worked.

Make sure your target folder is not being used in any other application.