# Maven Compilation Failure. No compiler is provided in this environment [Mac OS]

Tags: java, macos, maven

Maven suddenly stopped compiling with the error below. It was working this morning and I'm not sure what caused this.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ExampleProject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

###### Basic Information:

- OS: Mac
- Machine: MacBook Pro
- Java: 1.8.0_201 (jdk8)
- Maven: 3.8.1

What I tried:

- Checked for existence of Java compiler

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_201
```

- Check `$JAVA_HOME` : I got `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home`, which is correct for Mac OS according to [Maven's installation instructions](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)
- Added `mvn` to `PATH` before compiling
- Reinstalled Maven 3.8.1
- Reinstalled JDK8 and reset `JAVA_HOME` & added mvn to `PATH` again before compiling
- Added `sudo` to my command. In fact before adding `sudo`, I was facing [some sorta "failed to delete something"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489720/maven-failed-to-clean-project-failed-to-delete-org-ow2-util-asm-asm-tree) error.
- Restarting my laptop without using the "Reopen windows...." option.
- Adding the compiler option to `pom.xml`(I didn't need this when it was working this morning)
- Running `mvn -v` give me the output below

  ```
  Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.8.3
  Java Version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
  Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
  OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
  ```
- Running `java -version` gave me the output below:

  ```
  java version "1.8.0_201"
  Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
  Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201.b09, mixed mode)
  ```

###### Additional Info:

I am not using any IDE like Eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans. Just purely on terminal. Please base your answers on this.

It seems like there are 2 versions of Maven on my system, probably due to the reinstall. But prior to the reinstall, this problem already started

###### Reference (I've tried the solutions in here too)

https://roufid.com/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment/

## Edit

- I have already made sure that `JAVA_HOME` points to the JDK and not the JRE by consulting Maven's [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

Comment: The pointer to JAVA_HOME points to JRE and *not* to JDK...Also you are giving two different versions Maven the first one 3.8.1 while second output `mvn --version` shows 3.8.3 ?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. My Maven is version 3.8.3. As for JAVA_HOME, I followed Maven's installation guide https://maven.apache.org/install.html. Otherwise, what should JAVA_HOME be?

And you are right that the versions are different(there's no typo there). Probably due to the reinstall.

Comment: The output shows `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre` where the `jre` part is at the end... Try `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home` ..instead...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise. The output you are talking about is from mvn -v. I already set JAVA_HOME to the one without the "jre"

Answer (score 0):

Maven needs javac to compile your project. Can you try javac -version and see if your able to get an output.

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_201
```

If not set your JAVA_HOME to JDK not to JRE. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

If you are still getting this error, try opening another terminal for the environment variable to reflect. And try.

Regards

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reaching out. I have tried that too. I have edited my post to add the part about `javac`