# How to interpret these groovyscript/maven error messages

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I'm supposed to convert this huge list of CSV files into PX files (as in "PC Axis files"). In order to do this, I'm supposed to run a groovy script, which has been working for my predecessor without issues.

I follow the instructions and place the CSV-files in the in-directory. I'm supposed to just run the Windows Batch File in the folder below.

[image]

This does not work however, so I run the command prompt and change my directory to the folder above. I then type

```
mvn clean compile gplus:execute -Pprod
```

And I get an error message complaining that a certain file ("inputFiles.lst") can't be deleted.

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ se.fohm.pxweb ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.703 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-20T10:22:18+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project se.fohm.pxweb: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\compile\default-compile\inputFiles.lst -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

So I delete this file manually and it immediatly start complaining about another file

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< pxjobrunner:se.fohm.pxweb >----------------------
[INFO] Building pxjobrunner 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ se.fohm.pxweb ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.750 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-20T10:23:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project se.fohm.pxweb: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\compile\default-compile\createdFiles.lst -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

If i delete "that", it starts complaining about not being able to delete the whole directory. If I delete "that" it starts to complain about the parent directory and so forth.

I then try telling the command prompt to ignore these errors. I type

```
mvn clean compile gplus:execute -Pprod -Dmaven.clean.failOnError=false
```

I am now rewarded with an absolutely huge list of files which fails to get deleted (I only include a sample due to lack of space):

```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ---------------------< pxjobrunner:se.fohm.pxweb >----------------------
    [INFO] Building pxjobrunner 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ se.fohm.pxweb ---
    [INFO] Deleting C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\compile\default-compile
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\compile
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\maven-status
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\MailClient.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\JobHelper.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\InjectionType.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\IndicatorHelper.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\Indicator.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\FileUtils.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\Constants.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\Configuration.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\CommandHelper.java
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob
    [WARNING] Failed to delete C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm
    [WARNING] Failed to delete
```

At the end of the log I find several other errors, seeming to claim folders can't be written to since access has been denied (again I can include only a sample):

```
[INFO]
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO]
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  02:06 min 
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-20T10:52:42+01:00 
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.5:generateStubs (default) on project se.fohm.pxweb: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: startup failed: [ERROR] General error during conversion: C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\Configuration.java (Access is denied) 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Repos\folkhalsodata\pxjobbrunner\groovy\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\se\fohm\pxjob\Configuration.java (Access is denied) [ERROR]         at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) [ERROR]         at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270) [ERROR]       at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213) [ERROR]  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162) [ERROR]  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaStubGenerator.generateClass(JavaStubGenerator.java:104) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaStubCompilationUnit$2.call(JavaStubCompilationUnit.java:73) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1055) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaStubCompilationUnit.compile(JavaStubCompilationUnit.java:93) 
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [ERROR]         at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:118) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.doStubGeneration(AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.java:184) 
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.GenerateStubsMojo.execute(GenerateStubsMojo.java:58) 
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) 
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210) 
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156) 
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148) 
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
```

[UPDATE 1]

If I delete the entire target folder the script runs, but no px files are created in the out-folder. Near the end I find a note about non-valid indicators.

```
2023-03-20 12:16:27 INFO  JobHelper:? - 29 csv file(s)  found
2023-03-20 12:16:27 INFO  JobHelper:? - Indicators to be updated:a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,ea
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? - 0 valid indicators:
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? - 17 invalid indicators: g, n, e, b, h, c, j, f, i, o, ea, d, m, l, k, p, a
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [g: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, g: no header file can be found for the indicator!, g: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [n: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, n: no header file can be found for the indicator!, n: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [e: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, e: no header file can be found for the indicator!, e: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [b: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, b: no header file can be found for the indicator!, b: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [h: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, h: no header file can be found for the indicator!, h: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [c: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, c: no header file can be found for the indicator!, c: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [j: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, j: no header file can be found for the indicator!, j: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [f: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, f: no header file can be found for the indicator!, f: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [i: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, i: no header file can be found for the indicator!, i: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [o: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, o: no header file can be found for the indicator!, o: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [ea: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, ea: no header file can be found for the indicator!, ea: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [d: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, d: no header file can be found for the indicator!, d: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [m: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, m: no header file can be found for the indicator!, m: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [l: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, l: no header file can be found for the indicator!, l: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [k: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, k: no header file can be found for the indicator!, k: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [p: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, p: no header file can be found for the indicator!, p: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? -         [a: no set/ini file can be found for the indicator!, a: no header file can be found for the indicator!, a: no deployed px file path defined for the indicator!]
2023-03-20 12:16:27 DEBUG JobHelper:? - No valid indicator to update
2023-03-20 12:16:27 INFO  JobHelper:? - End of job
2023-03-20 12:16:27 INFO  JobHelper:? - List of erroneous files:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.782 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-20T12:16:27+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't code in groovy/maven/java at all, but I figure this might be a permission error somehow. I've contacted IT in order to be able to run the command prompt in administrator mode and/or kick out my predecessor if he's still somehow logged into the system (According to some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489720/maven-failed-to-clean-project-failed-to-delete-org-ow2-util-asm-asm-tree), that might be an issue.

Apart from this I'm not really sure what to do. Any ideas?

I don't really have access (at least to my knowledge) to some kind of fancy point-and-click interface, I have access the command prompt and that's it.

[UPDATE 2]

I managed to get administrator rights. That suppresses the first error, but the px-files still aren't generated. I get the same notes about invalid ini- and header files as above.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] your question to include the error messages as properly formatted text.

Comment: I unsuccessfully tried copying the errors from the log (since they aren't written to the errors folder for some reason), do you want me to copy these by hand?

Comment: My guess is that there's some permission problem. Try deleting (or moving away, if you're overly cautious) the entire `target/` directory, as it should only ever contain stuff that's generated during build time anyway.

Comment: No, copying by hand is almost worse (definitely worse for you and also likely worse for us due to the high chance of typos that will be hard to figure out). I want you to [learn to copy it](https://superuser.com/questions/295370/how-to-copy-text-in-the-windows-command-line-cmd), instead.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Okay, so I changed the pictures for actual code samples and I tried deleting the targets folder, updated question with results.

Comment: @Magnus,
i bet your user do not have permission of target folder without claiming admin privilege. try to run cmd as administrator and then run your mvn command. check that target folder is not open with another application - for example if you have target folder open in windows explorer - it could not be deleted. PS: still nothing about groovy...

Comment: @daggett I can't really do that without IT elevating my privileges or whatever. I've already contacted them about that but it will probably take a while.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Seeing as the first error messages and the error messages after deleting the Targe folder is distinct, should I create a separate question about the latter?

Comment: I believe this is still fundamentally the same problem, so I don't think you need a new question, just [edit] it with any more details you find out. Unfortunately I don't have any more ideas for you.